# Laravel [PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: laravel

While pushing homestead repo to live server, i encountered the following error.

I can confirm that i can connect to mysql from the command line using the variables set in the .env file.

I know that it has something to do with this particular setup, as i am effectively operating a similar laravel 5.1 project on the same host.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that on the error page that i was looking at the top message, which was 3/3. **Looking to the 1/3 (the first error) error helped me find the solution.**

Laravel was still using the homestead credentials.
i found this by searching:

```
grep -r "homestead" .
```

returns

```
./bootstrap/cache/config.php:        'database' => 'homestead',
```

To clear the cache all that was left was to do was clear the cache.

`php artisan config:cache`